# How to change the background color of cardview when the notification history clicked?

Tags: java, android

I have created a recycleview which display a list of notification history.  Here am using realm database which get notifications from onesignal.  I want to highlights the unclicked cardview in blue color. And once it clicked it should change the background color to white.

I have tried by using

```
CardView cardview = (CardView)  findViewById(R.Id.name);

cardview. SetCardBackgroundColor(COLOR.WHITE) ;
```

It's working on that time only.  Once I went back and open the app again means it's not changing.  What should I do?  Please help me.

Comment: `it's not changing` That means this part of your code is not getting called .. Debug your code to see what exactly is going on .

Comment: save the clicked position somewhere and according to that change your card color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy implementation, just make a boolean in you model class like "isClicked" and call in your `onBindViewHolder` like this:

```
{
  ModelClass mModelClass = mModelClass.get(position);
  CardView mCardView = holder.findViewById(R.id.mCardView_layout);
  if (mModelClass.isClicked())
     mCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Your_Color);
  else
     mCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Your_Color);
}
```

> **Untested Code**

You can add an onClickListener in here and change the boolean value of `isClicked` and update the recyclerview.

Comment: On OnBindViewHolder,  i cannot add the Cardview cardview = holder. findViewById (R.id.name) .  Here findViewById shows an error.

Answer (score 0):

card.setCardBackgroundColor(color);

In XML
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/black" can used in cardview tag .